Get the value from the plist if the key is in the variable
I'm writing code to generate the rss feed of my selfhost podcast and I need a function that would return a type depending on the file extension of podcast item.
For example, if the podcast file (item) has the extension mp4, I need to return the string video/mp4. This is needed to generate the tag <enclosure> as described in A Podcaster’s Guide to RSS.
This problem could be solved through a function to condition enumeration. For example,
(defun podcast-return-type (ext)
  "return type string for item file extension"
  (cond
   ((string= ext "m4a") (identity "audio/x-m4a"))
   ((string= ext "mp4") (identity "video/mp4"))
   ((string= ext "mp3") (identity "audio/mpeg"))
   ((string= ext "mov") (identity "video/quicktime"))
   ((string= ext "m4v") (identity "video/x-m4v"))
   ((string= ext "pdf") (identity "application/pdf"))
   (t (identity "not applyed"))))

But I wanted to solve it through a property list. I ran into a problem: I can't get the value if the key is stored in a variable.
(setq podcast-list '(mp4 "video/mp4" mp3 "audio/mpeg" pdf "application/pdf")) ;; key value
(setq ext (file-name-extension "~/podcast/podcast-item.mp4")) ---> "mp4"

(plist-get podcast-list ext) ----> nil
(plist-get podcast-list 'mp4) ----> "video/x-m4v"

How can I get the value of a plist if the key is in a variable? Or is there a more elegant way to solve this problem? I feel like the solution is somewhere on the surface, but I'm stuck.

That's because your keys are symbols and the value of ext is a string. Those are completely different types, so they never match.
You can convert your string to a symbol by interning it:
(plist-get podcast-list (intern ext))
"video/mp4"

You can also convert the keys to string, but then you need to specify a different comparison function in plist-get -  it uses eq by default which will not work for strings:
(setq podcast-list '("mp4" "video/mp4" "mp3" "audio/mpeg" "pdf" "application/pdf"))
(setq ext (file-name-extension "~/podcast/podcast-item.mp4"))
(plist-get podcast-list ext #'string=)
"video/mp4"

eq is much cheaper than string=, so most people would probably prefer the first version.

EDIT: I was intrigued by the performance figures the OP posted in a comment, so I tried to reproduce them with this file:
(defun podcast-return-type (ext)
  "return type string for item file extension"
  (cond
   ((string= ext "m4a") (identity "audio/x-m4a"))
   ((string= ext "mp4") (identity "video/mp4"))
   ((string= ext "mp3") (identity "audio/mpeg"))
   ((string= ext "mov") (identity "video/quicktime"))
   ((string= ext "m4v") (identity "video/x-m4v"))
   ((string= ext "pdf") (identity "application/pdf"))
   (t (identity "not applied"))))


(setq podcast-list '(m4a "audio/x-m4a" mp4 "video/mp4" mp3 "audio/mpeg" mov "/video/quicktime" m4v "video/x-m4v" pdf "application/pdf"))


(print (benchmark-run 100000 (podcast-return-type "mp4")))

(print (benchmark-run 100000 (plist-get podcast-list (intern "mp4"))))

(print (benchmark-run 100000 (podcast-return-type "pdf")))

(print (benchmark-run 100000 (plist-get podcast-list (intern "pdf"))))


Running it with emacs --batch --load test.el I got the following
results:

(0.026426384 0 0.0)              ;; function mp4

(0.015171091000000001 0 0.0)    ;; plist-get mp4

(0.043410812 0 0.0)               ;; function pdf

(0.016731469 0 0.0)               ;; plist-get pdf

I tried two keys: one near the beginning of the list and one near the end. The function shows a substantial slowdown between the two cases (almost a factor of 2), while the plist-get is about 7% slower in the second case.
But in neither case, did the function beat plist-get: the function is slower by a factor of 1.5 in the first case and by 2.5 in the second case. Note I did 100000 repetitions of each.
BTW, you can speed up your function  a bit by getting rid of the unnecessary identity function calls:
(defun podcast-return-type (ext)
  "return type string for item file extension"
  (cond
   ((string= ext "m4a") "audio/x-m4a")
   ((string= ext "mp4")  "video/mp4")
   ((string= ext "mp3")  "audio/mpeg")
   ((string= ext "mov")  "video/quicktime")
   ((string= ext "m4v")  "video/x-m4v")
   ((string= ext "pdf")  "application/pdf")
   (t "not applied")))

but even so, the plist-get implementation is still faster:

(0.022579204000000002 0 0.0)   ; function mp4

(0.012907366 0 0.0)              ; plist-get mp4

(0.038039411 0 0.0)              ; function pdf

(0.014557089 0 0.0)              ; plist-get pdf



Thank you it really works! I tested different ways and it turns out that using the function with conditions works a bit faster.
`(plist-get podcast-list-sym (intern ext)))) ;; time (0.001019 0 0.0)
(plist-get podcast-list-str ext #'string=))) ;; time (0.001877 0 0.0)
(benchmark-run 100 (podcast-return-type "mp4"))  ;;time (0.000163 0 0.0)`

I tried to replicate your findings but I came to the opposite conclusion. See my edit.


Or is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Yes, there is. Use the built in function that already does what you are building here:
(mailcap-extension-to-mime "pdf") -> "application/pdf"

Emacs actually already has a mime-table built-in. Check mailcap.el which is built-in into your Emacs. You can call mailcap-mime-types for a list of known extensions.
For the Elisp questions, as NickD noted, you are using symbols as keys, and file-name-extension will return you a string. As a note, you can use intern-soft, to achieve the similar as the suggested intern, depending on if you want to keep the symbol around, or just wish to use it temporarily:
(eq 'mp3 (intern-soft "mp3")) -> t

Alternatively you can use strings as keys in your plist:
(setq podcast-list '("mp4" "video/mp4" "mp3" "audio/mpeg" "pdf" "application/pdf"))

but you still have to use equal as the predicate:
(plist-get podcast-list "mp4" #'equal) -> "video/mp4"

A note, only recent versions of Emacs have plist-get function that accepts a predicate argument, but I think you can use the emacs-compat library to get around this if you are on an older Emacs.
As NickD suggests, in general we prefer to use eq, instead of equal, since it
compares pointers to objects, while equal compares the content of objects, so eq
is computationally cheaper. However, considering you are comparing up to
few characters, that really does not matter in practice. If you were to compare thousands of files in a loop, than perhaps it would matter, but considering the cost of interning a string, I wouldn't care in your case.
About your code, you could also do something like this:
(defun podcast-return-type (ext)
  "Return type string for item file extension"
  (pcase ext
    ("m4a" "audio/x-m4a")
    ("mp4" "video/mp4")
    ("mp3" "audio/mpeg")
    ("mov" "video/quicktime")
    ("m4v" "video/x-m4v")
    ("pdf" "application/pdf")))

As you see, we can skip passing things through the identity function, as you do in your original code. There is also no need for the property list at all, since we  get basically a mime-table via pcase.

Using a (presumably well-tested) built-in function always beats rolling your own.

Exactly. A common theme we see in Lisp(s) over and over, is that people often roll their own, instead of using something that already exists. Either because it is very easy, or they are not aware of the existing one. I am not sure if it is an argument for or against Lisp(s) in general, but it is de facto something we see constantly. Admittedly, mailcap.el is rather a niche library, so it is not strange that the original poster didn't know about it.
